# What species is this little white bird?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

[image]
This bird was found in my backyard in the north east of Italy. It's about 5cm long and can fly as high as 1.5m (so far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a white zebra finch: 
[image]

Comment: Such as... do you need instructions for an ophtalmologist.